# Textarea value saved to database weird characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, character-encoding

Information from a text area is being saved to my database when a form is submitted.  There is one case where the following characters are showing up in the field.

E.g.

`â€¢ Text`

And if I pull the data out of the database using java it looks like:

`�?� Text`

I'm guessing it has something to do with character encoding.  Would adding this tag  
`<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the top of my page fix it?  Or is there something I can do with the text area to clean it up before saving the value to a database?

This is not something I know how to reproduce on my own I just saw it while monitoring the database.  Any information or enlightenment on the subject would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with the `<meta>` tag?

Comment: UTF-8 end to end, or die. (yes, you need to specify UTF-8 on the page and ensure your DB is using it as well)

Comment: Well  I dont have a meta tag that is probably what I am missing.  I would try it however I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem to verify a fix.

Comment: Try adding this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: try html entity encode before storing, and html entity decode upon rerendering

Comment: @CopyDevil its only a bad idea if you have to search for it.  If the text is only for display purposes its fine.  Also, you can just search for the html encoded string if need be.

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks I'll make sure to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you have to set the MySQL connection to UTF-8.
For Example for PHP/MySQLi and MySQL:

```
$utf8_mysqli = $mysqli ->set_charset("utf8");
```

#### Quick example why you shouldn't encode with htmlentities() or the like:

**Without encoding:**

```
> INSERT INTO `table` (test) VALUES ("Max Ämerich"), ("50 €");
--------------------
| test        | ai |
====================
| Max Ämerich |  1 |
|   50 €      |  2 |
====================
```

**With encoding**

```
> INSERT INTO `table` (test) VALUES ("Max &auml;merich"), ("50 &euro;");
-------------------------
| test             | ai |
=========================
| Max &auml;merich |  1 |
|   50 &euro;      |  2 |
=========================
```

**Now try a SELECT**

> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE test = "50 €";

If the values are encoded, this will return 0 rows.

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure that I have `utf8` encoding set on my page and on my database like you and Diodeus suggested.  Seeing as your the only person that has answered and I feel that I have a better understanding of why that this issue is happening i'll mark this as accepted.